# Xcode builds crash on running app after changing certificate trust setting

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, keychain

I recently changed the my *iPhone Distribution Certificate's trust setting* to **Always trust** instead of **Use system defaults** (from keychain Access).

After changing this setting, all my app builds that are signed using this certificate crash on running with the following crash log below. After some debugging, I changed this certificate setting back to **Use system defaults** and this stops the crashes. Does anyone know why and how this trust setting might be causing the app to crash?

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)

Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Description: DYLD, Library not loaded: @rpath/AFNetworking.framework/AFNetworking | Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/MyApp.app/MyApp | Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find: | /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/MyApp.app/Frameworks/AFNetworking.framework/AFNetworking: code signing blocked mmap() of '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/MyApp.app/Frameworks/AFNetworking.framework/AFNetworking' | /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/MyApp.app/Frameworks/AFNetworking.framework/AFNetworking: code signing blocked mmap() of '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/MyApp.app/Frameworks/AFNetworking.framework/AFNetworking' | /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/MyApp.app/Frameworks/AFNetworking.framework/AFNetworking: code signing blocked mmap() o
Triggered by Thread:  0
```